# How to use App.config in .NET3.5 when using Remoting with out adding Remoting related configuation in App.config?

Tags: c#, remoting

I am trying to use an App.config for a Windows Service application which is hosting Remoting and is developed in .NET3.5. In that App.config, I would like to keep some values which I will be using across the solution. I am not adding Remoting relation configuration stuff to it. But while running application it is expecting Remoting related configuration stuff in App.config. I dont want to put Remoting related configuration in that file. How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: What kind of remoting configuration stuff is expected in the app.config?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure remoting programmatically,

to register a channel you can

```
IChannel tcpChannel = new TcpChannel(8888);
ChannelService.RegisterChannel(tcpChannel);
```

Basicly everything can be configured in code.

I would recommend [Ingo Rammer's Advanced .Net Remoting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590590252)!

Answer (score 0):

You could put your remoting configuration stuff in a separate file, then configure remoting by calling:

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfiguration.Configuration(myConfigFileName, true);
```